# VS Code + Typescript shows a different type depending on which value I hover first?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I noticed that in VS Code, sometimes some types will become `any`. Since `tsc` doesn't throw any errors such as "no implicit any", I assumed it was a VS Code display issue.

I realized the type VS Code reports can change depending on which value I hover first. E.g.:

[image]
[image]

In the first screenshot, I hovered `newReply` first and the type was `any`. In the second screenshot, I hovered `ReplyClass.insert` first and the type for `newReply` became `PostReply | RoomReply | ChatReply`. Afterwards, even if I hover over other values, the type VS Code shows stays the same. I have to restart the TS server or make a code change before VS Code can show a different type. I'm assuming VS Code is caching the type.

Is this a known VS Code/Typescript bug? I think the value `tsc` sees is probably `PostReply | RoomReply | ChatReply`, otherwise I'd get a "no implicit any" error. If this isn't a known issue, any ideas where I can look to resolve this?

Comment: TS and VSCODE version?

Comment: TS 4.6.4 & VS Code 1.67.2